# How to get data-tables in asp.net to show only certain data

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I cannot figure how to get the data to show only the entries with John. I am using dataTables, so not sure how to get it to work. When I launch the app it still shows all the users. Here is what I got so far any help would be appreciated. I am trying to get a where clause into the program do I create it in the model not in the controller.

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Asp.NetMVCCrud.Models;

namespace Asp.NetMVCCrud.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Employee
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult GetData()
        {
            using(DBModel db = new DBModel())
            {
               db.Employees.Where(Employee => Employee.Name == "John");
                List<Employee> empList = db.Employees.ToList<Employee>();
                return Json(new { data = empList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Employee model generated

```
namespace Asp.NetMVCCrud.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Postion { get; set; }
        public string Office { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Salary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

view index

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee List";
}

<h2>Employee Crud Operations</h2>
<table id="employeetable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section scripts{
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#employeetable").DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Employee/GetData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype":"json"

                },
                "columns": [

                    { "data": "Name" },
                      { "data": "Postion" },
                        { "data": "Office" },
                          { "data": "Age" },
                            { "data": "Salary" },

                ]

            });

        });
    </script>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line `db.Employees.Where(Employee => Employee.Name == "John")` isn't currently functionally doing anything. It is querying the db for employees with name John and then not doing anything with that data. I think you want

```
List<Employee> empList = db.Employees.Where(Employee => Employee.Name == "John").ToList();

return Json(new { data = empList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

you need to assign the filtered data to a variable so you have a reference to it and then return that data as part of your json

Answer (score 0):

Because your code is returning `empList` which is all the employees.

You have a LINQ query (this line `db.Employees.Where(Employee => Employee.Name == "John");`) to get the the filtered subset, but you are not executing that query or using the result of that to return the result.

Return only the filtered result. This should work

```
var filteredList = db.Employees.Where(e=> e.Name == "John").ToList();
return Json(new { data = filteredList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```